# How Do I Modify the Name of my admin.php page

Tags: php, web-config, admin, web-hosting

I had my website outsourced and the way it is set up now is on a web host. I have an example.com/**admin.php** page which I used to manually update my example.com/**index.php** page. I am trying to either:

1. change the name of the admin.php to something like admin_e6jm5kl89c23j09fn90.php so that it is not as easy for users to guess OR
2. add an authentication measure to access the admin.php page

EDIT: What I've tried-I have changed the name within the web host's file manager, but something gets disconnected behind the scenes and submitted updates do no update the database.

Comment: so how hard is it to log into the server and do `mv origname newname`?

Comment: I forgot to mention I have tried this in my description. Do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to name you admin page: admin_e6jm5kl89c23j09fn90.php
You just have to check if a Session Variable is set and in your admin loginform you have to set this Session Varaible:

### Set Session Variable

```
session_start();
$_SESSSION['admin'] = true;
```

### Check if Session Variable is set

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```